# Loading secret content in .profile when initializing bash/zsh

Tags: bash, shell, encryption, sh, zshrc

I want to include an `environment variable` with a secret Api key during shell initialization. But I do not want that environment variable to be exposed in a plain text file.

So, I was wondering if there is a built-in mechanism or script to do this.

I was thinking on a encrypted git repository using [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt). And when initializing (on .profile) decrypt it, source it and then encrypt it back to make unreadable to other users.

Comment: So...where will you store the key used to decrypt your secret file?

Comment: Encryption/decryption would be made using GPG keys with a passphrase. The passphrase will be entered once per session (using gnome-keyring or a gpg-agent). Similar as you do when using SSH keys with Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of `sh` functions and using [gpg](https://gnupg.org/) made it:

```
SECRETS_FILE=~/.secrets.sh
GPG_ID=yourgpgid@mydomain.com
profile_decrypt (){
  gpg -d ${SECRETS_FILE}.asc > ${SECRETS_FILE} # Decrypt file
  rm ${SECRETS_FILE}.asc
}

profile_encrypt () {
  gpg -ea -r ${GPG_ID} ${SECRETS_FILE} # Encrypt file using ascii output
  rm ${SECRETS_FILE}
}
profile_decrypt
source $SECRETS_FILE
profile_encrypt
```

Where `~/.secrets.sh` contains:

```
export API_KEY=<SECRET API KEY>
```

Including this functions on `.profile` decrypts, exports variables and encrypts them back everytime the terminal is loaded.

Comment: I've just made a shell plugin with this feature: https://github.com/gmatheu/shell-plugins/blob/master/README.md#profile-secrets